# Adobe Analytics - PurchaseID set with Timestamp Issue

Tags: adobe-analytics

We are having a lot of transactions on the site, so for this reason we are re-cycling our booking confirmation numbers/ order id numbers on the confirmation screen which is set into our purchaseID . Since we are re-using our booking confirmation number, in order to make our purchaseID unique we are adding timestamp to our purchaseID variable using pipe delimeter. So formula looks like:

purchaseID = order_id + '|' +  timestamp (current date).

My concern here is, let's say I make a booking today and my purchase id looks like -

purchaseID = 5747118 | 6-7-2019

Now I access my confirmation screen again tomorrow and after 2 days, 3 days and so on and I see adobe calls firing. Because I accessed my confirmation page on different dates my timestamp changed and thus my purchaseID is not unique anymore. Even though I am seeing my same booking confirmation page my purchaseID is not unique now. Does this mean, every time i view my confirmation screen on a different day my booking/revenue would be counted multiple times ? If yes, what's the best way to tackle this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like someone can go to your site, make a purchase and see the confirmation page, and then later on, go back to the same confirmation page without actually making another purchase. Maybe they bookmarked the page and come back to it later for reference. Or maybe they refreshed the page, because reasons.

Does your site charge their credit card for accessing the page again? I sure hope not. Your site/coding should be structured in a way that does not keep charging the customer more money every time they view the page again.

And your code logic for outputting Adobe Analytics should be structured in the same way: your coding logic should be that you only output purchase event and variables (e.g. `purchaseID`) *when a purchase actually occurs*.

In practice, this sometimes isn't easy to do because of  how the site is structured. So part of why `purchaseID`exists is to de-duplicate purchases, so that if purchase event and data is re-popped, it will be de-duped. But it only works if you output the *same* purchaseID when the visitor refreshes the page or otherwise comes back to it later on (where they aren't actually making another purchase).

Which it sounds like you were doing with the original booking confirmation number you pushed to `purchaseID`. But things went south when you decided to throw a current datestamp into the mix because you started recycling booking confirmation numbers. Well you can't do that. You can use a dynamic value such as the current date/timestamp as part of the value, but you must *remember* it, and output it in the future.

Maybe this involves adding an extra column to your database with the date/timestamp of purchase (which I have to assume you surely already have), and then pull that value when you pull the booking confirmation number.

Or maybe the solution involves stepping back and rethinking the fact you are recycling booking confirmation numbers. This seems like a bad idea to me. It's definitely a bad idea for your Adobe Analytics implementation, as you have seen for yourself. But is this not a bad idea in general? What happens if a customer buys something today and has # 12345 as proof of transaction to reference, and then tomorrow, a week, a year or whatever from now, some other customer gets the same number?

It stands to reason that you will end up with a mess on your hands, trying to sort out which customer bought what. Transaction ids by their nature are supposed to be forever unique to the transaction. So my very first recommended solution to you would be to stop recycling your booking confirmation numbers. Move to a different format if you need to (e.g. UUID).

Failing that, my next recommendation would be what I said a couple paragraphs up, about storing the date/timestamp in a column at the actual time of purchase (which surely you already have), and then grab and use that value along with the booking confirmation # to  use as delimited value, instead of generating the current date on the fly (which absolutely does not work).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for the detailed explanation and recommendation. To follow, I tried making a test booking and accessing the confirmation page again. Weirdly, I cannot get to confirmation page and it's accessible only once. So right now I am confused, as this scenario of viewing confirmation page multiple times is not possible how does my adobe report same booking id with different timestamp for the same user ?

Comment: Also another issue I noticed, for a booking id with a specific timestamp, 3 bookings were recorded. So basically the reported booking id was 41355891- 2019-05-05 timestamp. When i broke down this booking Id by day assuming all 3 bookings for this Id happened on same day, I was shocked to see 2 of these bookings were made on a different day and year i.e. in 2018. My timestamp code that i wrote on the fly seems to be working correctly by giving current date. But this here again is a bizzare case.

Comment: One configuration setting I wanted to point out is the booking Id stored in eVar is set to expire after visit, which means the value for booking id with timestamp persists beyond confirmation. Maybe this is one issue and it needs to be expired after the purchase event in adobe

Comment: @reddevil okay well ultimately I cannot answer most of your questions as I do not have access to your site nor know how it is coded. But if you are seeing multiple instances of the booking id (but with different timestamp prefixes) then clearly you are either able to access the page for it to populate again, OR multiple visitors are being given the same core booking id (which I recommended against doing), OR you are outputting it in other (presumably unexpected) places.

Comment: @reddevil but if you are duplicating `purchaseID` to an `eVar` then yes, you should set it to expire on `purchase`.